# Bash Script Returning Value and Echo

Tags: bash

I'm following the code mentioned [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/return-values-bash-functions) but it doesn't echo $result. Here is my code, I added quotations around the "$result". The echo in myfunc works, but the echo outside the function doesn't work. What is the problem? How do I fix it?

My Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

function myfunc()
{
    local myresult="Hello World"

}

result=$(myfunc)   
echo "$result"
```

Comment: which function is it called from? Is this the only small script?

Comment: @almasshaikh - Yes, it's the complete script. I'm just copying the code that was in the link I posted.

Comment: [Returning Values from Bash Functions](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/return-values-bash-functions)

Comment: @lurker - That is the link I posted. I got the code from there.

Comment: But it seems you mixed up their two examples. You were attempting to use half of one with half of the other.

Comment: @lurker - I was incorrect. I assumed the echo in the function wasn't needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

function myfunc()
{
    local myresult="Hello World"
    echo "$myresult" # the function need to return something
}

result=$(myfunc)   
echo "$result"
```

Comment: Is the variable set in $result variable? Can I now use my $result

Comment: @CharlesWhitfield `\`\`` and `$()` are the same, will capture standard output of inner command and set it to a variable.

Comment: @CharlesWhitfield sure it does

Comment: Thanks - I thought the echo in the function wasn't needed. Guess I was wrong.